# How can I obfuscate inline C# code in ASPX file?

Tags: asp.net

Last couple of days I have downloaded and tested almost every .net obfuscation app, but none is doing what I need.

I just want to make the source code as hard as possible for someone to read, all strings obfuscated, function names, variables etc all obfuscated. Is it possible? Is there a tool that can encryption inline C# code in my aspx page?

Comment: What makes you think there is C# code visible to the client viewing the page? All they see is html that is generated by the code.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the view source and indicate what you are trying to obfuscate? I know view state control data is encoded(not encrypted so decoding is possible) for example but am not sure what specifically you are trying to hide.

Comment: I know it's not.visible to users, I  going to share code with many people. Don't want them to see plain and raw code and don't want to send precompiled ASP.NET DLL